# C++ "Proper" way of dealing with exceptions

Tags: c++, boost, exception, boost-asio

I'm programming a ROS Node which will likely be used by others and that's why I want to follow common guidelines. Sometimes I would like to add additional information to the exception, but I'm not sure how to do it. Here's an example of where that would be handy:

My ROS node connects to a serial device using the boost library. Under linux the permissions need to be set for /dev/ttyUSB0 for example or boost won't be able to open a serial connection and terminate the program.

Here's the original exception message copied from the console:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::system::system_error> >'
what():  open: Permission denied
Aborted (core dumped)
```

As I know what the problem might be, I want to provice the user with additional information. That's why I wrapped the line causing the problem with a try/catch block:

```
try{
    serial = new boost::asio::serial_port (io, port);
}
catch(const std::exception& e)
{
    cerr << "EXCEPTION CAUGHT: Boost::asio::serial_port could not open a connection. Make sure that you have read/write access to the serial port (run: sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyUSB0)" << endl;
    cerr << endl << "Original exception:" << endl;
    throw;
}
```

Is this a good or bad way of dealing with this situation? Thanks in advance

Comment: Only my opinion, but as a general rule of thumb, deal with exceptions as early as possible, but not earlier. Printing error information at that place might be a bad idea. For example think about a situation where multiple serial adapters are available and you want to try all of them. Your function would print out misleading information. Instead, create a custom type or add further information (using e.g. Boost.Exception) at that place and print out error messages later, e.g. in your main() or at a place where you can recover from that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this a good or bad way of dealing with this situation?

Only you can know that, as only you know what your application does and what it's flow is.

A few guidelines (which may not apply to your case):

1. Catch the most specialized exception that deals with your case (as @Johny mentioned, try `boost::system::system_error`).
2. If you are printing a message when catching the exception, also print e.what(). It may be, that in some cases you will get a `boost::system::system_error` for a different reason than the one related to read permissions (i.e. /dev/ttyUSB0 is not there at all?). If you do not print `e.what()` you will end up loosing the actual error cause and mis-identifying it as a permission problem.
3. Also print e.code() (if you are using `boost::system::system_error`). This will give you the actual (system level) error code, identifying the error cause much more precisely.
4. If you can recover from this error, do not `throw;` it further. Your application will not `terminate()` if you do that.

Comment: Okay I'm printing the original exception by throwing it, looks like this is not the good way of doing it :) Thanks for your advice

Answer (score 4):

You are catching all std::exceptions. I think you should catch only `boost::system::system_error` exception.

Otherwise you can be printing misleading error report (ie. in case of allocation failure you would catch also `std::bad_alloc`).